How to prove a profit function is legitimate
A farmer produces using two inputs; labour (l) and fertilizer (k). The profit function is given by π=p²/√wr
Where p is price of maize per bag and r,w are the unit prices for fertilizer and labour respectively. K is measured in 1kg bags and L is measured in man hours.
Question; a legitimate Profit function is convex and positively linearly homogeneous in both input and output prices. Is the above function legitimate?

$\pi (tw, tr, tp)=t^2 p^2 / t (wr)^{1/2} = tp^2 / (wr)^{1/2} = t\pi (w, r, p) $
Hence, profit function is linearly homogeneous in both input and output prices.
